# Syntax for calling a Lambda Expression with Delegates

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

I found the following example which works well:

```
private static bool GreaterTwo(int arg)
{
    return arg > 2;
}

public static void GreaterTwoSample()
{
    Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Where(GreaterTwo);
}
```

What would be the syntax for using `GreaterTwo` with another parameter within the WHERE-Lambda:

```
private static bool GreaterTwoSmallerArg2(int arg, int arg2)
{
    return arg > 2 && arg < arg2;
}
```

**UPDATE:** thanks to HugoRune's answer, here is another working example with 2 parameters

```
public static void LimitationSample()
{
    Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Where(IsBetween(2, 5));
}
private static Func<int, bool> IsBetween(int min, int max)
{
    return x  => x > min && x < max;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Where(...)` requires a function that takes a single int as a parameter and returns a bool, there is no way around that.

The two usual ways to do this are:

- pass the name of an existing function *that takes an int*, i.e.

  ```
  Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Where(YourFunctionThatTakesAnIntAndReturnsBool);
  ```
- pass a lambda expression

  ```
  Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Where(x=>{Expression_that_returns_a_bool})
  ```

So the basic solution if you want to use a function that needs *two integers* is to pack it into a lambda expression i.e

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Where(x=>GreaterTwoSmallerArg2(x, 5))
```

But if you want more syntactic sugar, you can make a **function that returns a function**,

```
private static Func<int,bool> funcGreaterTwoSmallerArg2(int arg2)
{
    return x => GreaterTwoSmallerArg2(x, arg2);
    // OR: return x => x > 2 && x < arg2;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Where(funcGreaterTwoSmallerArg2(5));
```

This syntax should be used with care, it can make the source hard to understand. But sometimes it is warranted, if you reuse a specific lambda often enough, or it is particularly complicated.

Comment: i'm new to this, i transfered your example to one with 2 Parameters in my answer. What does x and y stand for?

Comment: The x and y stand for the two int in `Func<int,int,bool>`. `(x,y) => x > min && x < max;` is equivalent to `bool myFunc(int x,int y){return x>min&&x<max;}`. However the y seems unnecessary in your case, I am not sure why you would need it. And I think the example you provided will not work, `Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Where()` requires a `Func<int,bool>`, not `Func<int,int,bool>`

Comment: Regarding your earlier edit: There actually is an [overload for Where that takes two int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418%28v=vs.100%29.aspx): the second int is the *index* of the element. So you would use that if for some reason you wanted to compare not only the value of each element in your list, but also its position.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like below:

```
public static void GreaterTwoSample(int arg2)
{
    Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Where(x=>GreaterTwoSmallerArg2(x, arg2));
}
```

Comment: +1 this is the correct answer you may want to add that `Where(GreaterTwo);` is a syntactic sugar for `Where(x => GreaterTwo(x));`

Comment: @Selman22 .. and i guess there is no sugar-way for a second parameter?

Comment: @Selman22 Behavior of these two syntaxes is similar, but different, in some cases very different.

Comment: @fubo is you mean just passing the method name instead of using a delegate, no, since the signature for `GreaterTwoSmallerArg2` does not match the signature for the parameter to `Where`.

Answer (score 1):

`Where<T>` takes a delegate that has a single `T` input and a `bool` output (aka predicate).  To use a method that has two parameters you'd have to project to it using a lambda:

```
private static bool GreaterTwoSmallerArg2(int arg, int arg2)
{
    return arg > 2 && arg < arg2;
}

public static void GreaterTwoSample()
{
    Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Where(i => GreaterTwoSmallerArg2(i, {some other value));
}
```